# Width is shrink after increasing the width & height 2 times openGL C++

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am rendering video on `GLSurfaceView` by openGL. The openGL portion is written on C++ in native portion. This is my render routine:

```
void VideoRenderOpenGL2::Render(const unsigned char *pData)
{
    ......................
    // GL_OPERATION is a macro, nothing special
    GL_OPERATION(glUseProgram(m_program))

    UpdateTextures(pData); // other routine, I will post the function if needed

    bool bClear = true;
    float vpx = 0.0f;
    float vpy = 0.0f;
    float vpw = 1.0f;
    float vph = 1.0f;
    int nOrientation = 0;

    float uLeft, uRight, vTop, vBottom;
    uLeft = vBottom = 0.0f;
    uRight = m_uvx;
    vTop = m_uvy;

    GLfloat squareUvs[] = {
            uLeft, vTop,
            uRight, vTop,
            uLeft, vBottom,
            uRight, vBottom
    };

    if (bClear) {
        GL_OPERATION(glViewport(0, 0, m_nDisplayWidth, m_nDisplayHeight))
        GL_OPERATION(glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1))
        GL_OPERATION(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }

    GLfloat squareVertices[8];

    // drawing surface dimensions
    int screenW = m_nDisplayWidth;
    int screenH = m_nDisplayHeight;
    if (nOrientation == 90 || nOrientation == 270) {
        screenW = m_nDisplayHeight;
        screenH = m_nDisplayWidth;
    }

    int x,y,w,h;
    // Fill the smallest dimension, then compute the other one using the image ratio
    if (screenW <= screenH) {
        float ratio = m_nTextureHeight / (float)m_nTextureWidth;
        w = screenW * vpw;
        h = w * ratio;
        if (h > screenH) {
            w *= screenH /(float) h;
            h = screenH;
        }
        x = vpx * m_nDisplayWidth;
        y = vpy * m_nDisplayHeight;
    } else {
        float ratio = m_nTextureWidth / (float)m_nTextureHeight;
        h = screenH * vph;
        w = h * ratio;
        if (w > screenW) {
            h *= screenW / (float)w;
            w = screenW;
        }
        x = vpx * screenW;
        y = vpy * screenH;
    }
    // here m_nDisplayWidth = 5536, m_nDisplayHeight = 3114, w = 5536, h = 3114, x = 0, y = 0, screenW = 5536, screenH = 3114, m_nTextureWidth = 1280, m_nTextureHeight = 720
    squareVertices[0] = (x - w * 0.5) / screenW - 0.;
    squareVertices[1] = (y - h * 0.5) / screenH - 0.;
    squareVertices[2] = (x + w * 0.5) / screenW - 0.;
    squareVertices[3] = (y - h * 0.5) / screenH - 0.;
    squareVertices[4] = (x - w * 0.5) / screenW - 0.;
    squareVertices[5] = (y + h * 0.5) / screenH - 0.;
    squareVertices[6] = (x + w * 0.5) / screenW - 0.;
    squareVertices[7] = (y + h * 0.5) / screenH - 0.;

    GL_OPERATION(glViewport(0, 0, m_nDisplayWidth, m_nDisplayHeight))

    GLfloat mat[16];
#define VP_SIZE 1.0f
    float vpDim = VP_SIZE / (2 * m_scaleFactor);

#define ENSURE_RANGE_A_INSIDE_RANGE_B(a, aSize, bMin, bMax) \
        if (2 * aSize >= (bMax - bMin)) \
        a = 0; \
        else if ((a - aSize < bMin) || (a + aSize > bMax)) { \
            float diff; \
            if (a - aSize < bMin) diff = bMin - (a - aSize); \
            else diff = bMax - (a + aSize); \
            a += diff; \
        }

    float zoom_cx = 0.0f;
    float zoom_cy = 0.0f;

    ENSURE_RANGE_A_INSIDE_RANGE_B(zoom_cx, vpDim, squareVertices[0], squareVertices[2])
    ENSURE_RANGE_A_INSIDE_RANGE_B(zoom_cy, vpDim, squareVertices[1], squareVertices[7])

    LoadOrthographicMatrix(
            zoom_cx - vpDim,
            zoom_cx + vpDim,
            zoom_cy - vpDim,
            zoom_cy + vpDim,
            0, 0.5, mat);

    GL_OPERATION(glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[UNIFORM_PROJ_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, mat))

#define degreesToRadians(d) (2.0 * 3.14157 * d / 360.0)
    float rad = degreesToRadians(nOrientation);

    GL_OPERATION(glUniform1f(m_uniforms[UNIFORM_ROTATION], rad))

    GL_OPERATION(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0))
    GL_OPERATION(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[Y]))
    GL_OPERATION(glUniform1i(m_uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_Y], 0))
    GL_OPERATION(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1))
    GL_OPERATION(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[U]))
    GL_OPERATION(glUniform1i(m_uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_U], 1))
    GL_OPERATION(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2))
    GL_OPERATION(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[V]))
    GL_OPERATION(glUniform1i(m_uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_V], 2))

    GL_OPERATION(glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices))
    GL_OPERATION(glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX))
    GL_OPERATION(glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_UV, 2, GL_FLOAT, 1, 0, squareUvs))
    GL_OPERATION(glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_UV))

    GL_OPERATION(glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4))
}
```

And this is `LoadOrthographicMatrix`:

```
void VideoRenderOpenGL2::LoadOrthographicMatrix(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far, float* mat)
{
    float r_l = right - left;
    float t_b = top - bottom;
    float f_n = far - near;
    float tx = - (right + left) / (right - left);
    float ty = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    float tz = - (far + near) / (far - near);

    mat[0] = (2.0f / r_l);
    mat[1] = mat[2] = mat[3] = 0.0f;

    mat[4] = 0.0f;
    mat[5] = (2.0f / t_b);
    mat[6] = mat[7] = 0.0f;

    mat[8] = mat[9] = 0.0f;
    mat[10] = -2.0f / f_n;
    mat[11] = 0.0f;

    mat[12] = tx;
    mat[13] = ty;
    mat[14] = tz;
    mat[15] = 1.0f;
}
```

Suppose, my device dimension is `1080 x 1557` and I am trying to render `2768 x 1557` (height equal to device height and corresponding width keeping aspect ratio with `1280 x 720`) sized video on the `GLSurfaceView`. Everything works fine so far and `Render(const unsigned char *pData)` is properly rendering and `glViewport(0, 0, m_nDisplayWidth, m_nDisplayHeight)` is working fine.

But when I want to load video twice the size of `2768 x 1557` I mean `5536 x 3114` the video shinked/congested (not truncated) across X axis. The `Render(...)` is drawing the full contents of video, but not using the full canvas. I can't figure it out what's wrong here. Why the video is congested across X axis? 
It is to be noted that, the video is rendered more congested when I increased the width & height more than 2 times. Its okay till `2768 x 1557`

Comment: You might be exceeding some size limit. For example, query the values for `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` with `glGetIntegerv()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I checked the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` and it gives me `4096` for both for my device. And I was trying to enlarge my viewport as `5536 x 3114` so definitely it exceeded the limit. Now I know the highest limit and enlarging my viewport width & height according to allowable factor so that it won't exceed the limit. Please post this comment as answer so that I can accept & upvote it. Thank you very much for saving my several days, Sir :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be exceeding limits of your OpenGL implementation. Particularly, the maximum texture size and maximum viewport dimensions could come into play.

To query the maximum texture size, use:

```
GLint maxTexSize = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTexSize);
```

and for the maximum viewport dimensions:

```
GLint viewportDims[2] = {0};
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS, viewportDims);
```

Typical values for these limits are as low as 2K for current low end devices, and possibly even lower for older devices. 4K and 8K are very common for current mainstream devices. Recent high end mobile GPUs support sizes up to 16K.

So before you try sizes over 4K, you should definitely check these limits. It's very likely that your 5536x3114 size will be beyond the limit of some fairly recent devices.